# PHP DateTime Compares to end date

Tags: php, datetime

I am having a problem to make my button disabled by comparing the today's datetime with end date on database. I made the conditions and it doesn't work on 1 day deadline, ex: `2023-07-31 00:00:00` with `2023-07-31 00:00:00`.

These are the code that I've tried :

```
// Variables
// $request_project->start_date (contains the startdate with datetime data type also user defined)
// $request_project->end_date (contains the deadline with datetime data type also user defined)
$startDate = new DateTime($request_project->start_date); //
$endDate = new DateTime($request_project->end_date);
$startDateTime = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00-00-00';
$endDateTime = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23-59-59';

$startDateString = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$endDateString = $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I want to compare the end date that user defined is `'<='` todays datetime, it will make the button active and having the `btn-primary` class, else it will add the `disabled` and change the `btn-primary` to `btn-secondary`.

```
<?php if($endDateString <= $endDateTime) {?> 
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-hover w-100 mt-2" 
  onclick="doSomething()">Apply Now <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
  <?php } else { ?>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-hover w-100 mt-2 disabled" 
    onclick="doSomething()">Apply Now <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"> 
   </i></a>
  <?php } ?>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-soft-warning btn-hover w-100 mt-2 
  bookmark" id="<?=$request_project->id?>"><i class="uil uil-bookmark"> 
  </i> Add Bookmark</a>
```

instead of executing the else block, it always executed the if block of code even when the end_date is already past the todays date.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The predicament you are encountering appears to be linked to how you are comparing the end date with the current date and time. The issue lies in the manner you are constructing the `$endDateTime` variable using the `date()` function.

In your code, you are utilizing `'Y-m-d'` as the layout for `date()`, which denotes it only includes the year, month, and day, but no time. Then, you concatenate `' 23-59-59'` to the date, which results in an erroneous datetime layout.

To address this problem, you should modify the `$endDateTime` variable to include the entire time (hours, minutes, and seconds) in the accurate format before performing the comparison. You can achieve this using the `date()` function with the format `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`, like this:

```php
$endDateTime = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
```

Now, `$endDateTime` will possess the correct format, and your comparison should work as anticipated.

Here's the updated code:

```php
<?php
$startDate = new DateTime($request_project->start_date);
$endDate = new DateTime($request_project->end_date);
$endDateTime = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
$startDateString = $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$endDateString = $endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if ($endDateString <= $endDateTime) {
    ?>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-hover w-100 mt-2" onclick="doSomething()">Apply Now <i
                class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-hover w-100 mt-2 disabled" onclick="doSomething()">Apply Now <i
                class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i></a>
    <?php
}
?>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-soft-warning btn-hover w-100 mt-2 bookmark"
   id="<?= $request_project->id ?>"><i class="uil uil-bookmark"></i> Add Bookmark</a>
```

With this adjustment, the code should now appropriately disable the button when the end date has passed today's date.

Comment: Tried it and it works just like i wanted. I did found the other way to make it works too thankfully, i use this condition `$endDateString >= $startDateTime && $endDateString <= $endDateTime`. Thanks for the explanation tho, really appreciate it!